# Python Can't find the second line in text file

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have a problem. When I search for the ID, the information appears only on the first line of the textfile. But when search for another ID that isn't on the first line, can't find it

```
import random
def create_sup():
    with open("supplier.txt","a+") as file:
        sup_name = input("Enter New Supplier's Name : ")
        sup_idgen = random.randint(0,9999)
        sup_id = sup_idgen
        print("Supllier ID : ",sup_id)
        sup_city = input("Enter New Supplier's City : ")
        sup_contact = int(input("Enter New Supplier's Contact Number : "))
        sup_email = input("Enter New Supplier's Email : ")
        columnsup = [sup_name,sup_id,sup_city,sup_contact,sup_email]
        file.write(str(columnsup)+"\n")


def s_searchbyid():
    with open("supplier.txt","r") as file:
        data = file.readline().split("\n")
        id = input("Enter Supplier ID : ")
        for line in data:
            if id in line:
                print(line)
```

Comment: Do you want actually to write the variables as a list, or would just having them separated by commas be better?

Answer (score 0):

The `readline` method reads only one line. In your case you read one line and split it based on newline '\n' (there is none) so what you eventually end up with is a one element list.

Use `data = file.read().split("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your program:

```py
import random


def create_sup():
    sup_name = input("Enter New Supplier's Name: ")
    sup_idgen = random.randint(0, 9999)
    sup_id = sup_idgen
    print("Supplier ID : ", sup_id)
    sup_city = input("Enter New Supplier's City: ")
    sup_contact = int(input("Enter New Supplier's Contact Number: "))
    sup_email = input("Enter New Supplier's Email: ")
    # Only open file when necessary.
    with open('supplier.txt', 'a') as file_1:
        file_1.write(f'{sup_name}, {sup_id}, {sup_city}, {sup_contact}, {sup_email}\n')


def s_searchbyid():
    sup_id = input("Enter Supplier ID : ")
    # Only open file when necessary.
    with open('supplier.txt', 'r') as file_1:
        # Iterate over the lines of the file. Yes, it's that simple!
        for line in file_1:
            if sup_id in line:
                print(line)
```

Of course, this code does not have the problem you were facing. There are a few comments to explain the changes.

Let me know if you have any questions or if something is unclear :)